# David marooned in Alien: Covenant

Tags: plot-explanation, alien-covenant

In Alien: Covenant, David tells the crew that he is marooned on the planet. We later see he arrived on the planet with an engineer spaceship. The crew finds the spaceship crashed in Covenant when they land before David comes and rescues them with a flare gun.

Is it ever explained if this is David's ship or how he marooned himself after coming to the planet with a working ship?

To me this ties into the other question I saw on here about the coincidence of the Covenant crew finding the signal. If David had a working ship, he could have gone and tested his creation elsewhere rather than being marooned but I don't remember any good explanation for how he became marooned.

Comment: The ship didn't crash there? That's what wiki says his explanation is.

Comment: He lies, obviously: " The payload accidentally deployed when we were landing. In the confusion we lost control of the ship. Elizabeth -- Dr. Shaw -- died in the crash" - the flashback says he released it intentionally. And Dr. Shaw took a different bus.  How he comes to crash the same ship in the woods, it's not made clear.

Answer (score -1):

Granted, this isn't obvious based on how the movies are named but Alien: Covenant is a sequel to:

[Prometheus](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1446714/)

> Following clues to the origin of mankind, a team finds a structure on a distant moon, but they soon realize they are not alone.

I don't know if I should give *too* much away here but if you have seen the sequel then the prequel's plot may have been spoiled already.

David was part of the crew in the first movie and survives that ordeal.  He does NOT have a working ship at the end of that movie if I recall correctly and the song that the crew in the second movie as a signal is a trap of sorts so David can attempt his experiment with new "subjects"

Regarding the movie titles, I think the addition of the "Alien" to the sequel meant to tie these two into the main Alien chronology as a precursor to the other series.

UPDATE: Since answering this, a comment by [blobbymcblobby](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/93971/blobbymcblobby) reminded me that he did have a working spaceship at the end of the movie so this is how he got to the new planet in Alien: Covenant where:

> He unleashed the "black goo" discovered in the first movie that the Engineer used to wipe out David's crew in the first movie.  His release of this "black goo" on this planet's proto-Engineers (whose culture is similar but distinct from the Engineers of the first movie) could be seen as an act of revenge or just a cruel experiment by a curious, yet heartless, android

Comment: ? I thought they got another ship at the end of Prometheus? ("DAVID: It's not the only ship. There are many others. I can operate them.") That was the one that got them to the Engineers world and where David nuked it. Because we don't see the same ship anywhere at the city (or even that floating receiving/docking ship), he must have crash landed it in the woods (for some reason?), which is the one they find (with the dog tags). OTTOMH...

Comment: There is a time gap between the two movies where David potentially crashed into the place where he is found in the second movie.

Comment: yes, that would be after dropping the fleas on those below, and then 'crashing' it in the woods.